# Can I transfer voice memos and notes from iphone to idrive usb drive?

Tags: iphone, usb, notes.app, voice-memo

I am a Linux user and do not use iTunes. There are 2 way usb drives around that allow one to attach them to iphone and transfer media using supplied app as well as use them as USB drive on a computer.

Before I commit to buy a usb drive I would like to know if it is possible to transfer text notes and voice memos from iphone to it? Being able to view them in the app is not important.

Also is it possible that any corporate software like wmvare airwatch will block it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am using iFalshDevice App and a generic brand idrive.
Cannot transfer voice memos in bulk. But with each individual one- tap on it - "share" and "copy to iFlashDevice". Now this will copy it to "App Storage -> Inbox" which is not really your drive yet, it looks like a clipboard area to transfer things. Select all voice memos there and copy them to the device in iFlashDrive App. This works with ios11 and 12.